# issue with powershell script to convert multiple excel files to csv

Tags: windows, powershell

Converting all the excel files in a specified directory using the below code. When I try to convert one file to csv it works as intended but when I try to convert all excel files to csv nothing happens no exception thrown, and the files are not converted.

```
$path = get-childitem -path "\\sharedrive\excelfiles\" -filter *.xlsx

foreach ($file in $path) 
{

$Excelfilename = $file.fullname
$CSVfilename = "" + $file.Basename

$xlCSV=6 

$Excel = New-Object -comobject Excel.Application 
$Excel.Visible = $False 
$Excel.displayalerts=$False 
$Workbook = $Excel.Workbooks.Open($ExcelFileName) 
$Workbook.SaveAs($CSVfilename,$xlCSV) 
$Excel.Quit() 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this same issue before, and this technet article was very useful: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730962.aspx

Basically you're doing everything right, but the .Quit() method isn't exactly what you're looking for since it gets rid of the program but not the com object.  We need to go one layer further and call the .NET Framework to release the COM object like below, then release the $Excel variable.

`$Excel.Quit()`

`[System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($Excel)`

`Remove-Variable $Excel`

This should give you what you're looking for and clean up your environment appropriately, allowing you to loop back through and make the change to all the .csv's